# System of three linear equations with unknown constant

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a linear system with three equations:

$$\begin{align}
x + y + z &= 3a\\
x + 2y + (a+2)z &= a\\
x - (a+1)y - z &= 0
\end{align}$$

I want to find values for a where the system is inconsistent in addition to the values of $x, y, z$ and $a$ for where the system is consistent.

How should one approach a problem like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With $$z=x-(a+1)y$$ we get
$$2x+y-(a+1)y=3a$$
and
$$2x-ay=3a$$
eliminating $x$ we obtain
$$-\frac{3a(a+3)}{2}y=-\frac{3a(a+3)}{2}$$
Now you can do the rest!

Comment: Thanks for your help Dr. Graubner! :)